# Ruby - calling a class variable/method through duck typing?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to access a class variable through duck typing, here's what the code looks like-

```
Class Foo
 self.league = League.New
```

And within the League class I have the following

```
@@some_array = ['A','B','C']
def self.some_array
   @@some_array
end
```

But when I go to use my duck type to call that value, I get a "method not found" error

```
league.some_array
```

I found that if I declare the method as an instance method, it will work-

```
def some_array
  @@some_array
end
```

But then I need to declare each method twice, and in other parts of my app I currently call `League.Some_Array` because I just need those values, it doesn't really benefit me to do League.new.

What's the best practice here?

Edit: If you're going to downvote the question, could you at least tell me why it's a bad question? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of: `cattr_reader` or `cattr_accessor`. `cattr_reader :some_array` for example would allow you to avoid the definition of the two getter methods.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann, that's good to know and I could use that. I'm still wondering if there's any way to get the class method through duck typing though.

Comment: What does it mean to "use a duck type"? Duck typing means that it is the _behavior_ of objects that matter, not their inheritance. @spickermann, `cattr_reader` and its ilk are rails-only. This question is only tagged ruby.

Comment: That's what I'm doing here, is it not? For clarity sake of the question, I'm statically setting league to be a certain class, in reality it could be several different classes. I'm expecting all of them to respond to ``some_array``. If the answer is when duck typing, it type only responds to instance methods and not class methods, that's fine, I just can't find anywhere that says that's the case.

Comment: @MajorMajor if the problem has to do with duck typing, you should demonstrate that in the question by having multiple classes that should be interchangeable. If the problem is just with avoiding the repetition of defining multiple getters, I don't see what that has to do with duck typing.

Comment: If it's impossible to get a class method from a "duck", then that answers my question.

Comment: Nothing in Ruby can be accurately called "a duck type" or "a duck". Duck typing has to do with Ruby's system of method resolution. I think this terminology is obscuring the intent of your question.

Comment: Got it, I can see why it was worded poorly and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a method like `attr_reader` which works for class variables.

```
module ClassAttributes
  def cattr_reader cattr
    define_singleton_method(cattr) { class_variable_get("@@#{cattr}") }
    define_method(cattr) { self.class.send(cattr) }
  end
end

class Foo
  extend ClassAttributes

  @@bar = 10

  cattr_reader :bar
end

Foo.bar     # => 10
Foo.new.bar # => 10
```

Comment: So this actually works perfectly, I don't understand why it works but me doing ``def self.some_array`` in the League class doesn't, but I'll just revisit it when I have a better understanding.

Comment: The `define_singleton_method` is like `def self.some_array` and `define_method` is like `def some_array`. Classes and instances in Ruby call totally different methods, but defining two identical methods with the same name makes it look like they share a method. _That's_ duck typing.